# Issue with Jenkins on Kubernetes when building docker containers

Tags: docker, jenkins, kubernetes, containers, google-kubernetes-engine

I have setup jenkins to run on GKE kubernetes cluster. I wrote the Jenkinsfile to define CI/CD pipeline. But when it reaches the docker build command, it gives me the following error:
"Segmentation fault (core dumped)
Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE"

After that I setup a new test job and run random command and it executes successfully but when I run docker version, I get the same error. The error comes when I run docker commands. I have restarted my jenkins pod, freshly setup a new jenkins instance on the cluster but the error was still there. I need help!! Any feedback is much appreciated.

Regards,

Comment: hello! please help to share any relevant code or scripts. perhaps, a little peek will reveal some insights on how to help on your situation.

Comment: Hey! Just running in to this same issue myself, so wondering if you made any progress with it?

Thanks!

Comment: Same here, any solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you are having an issue is because you are trying to run docker inside a container. The Jenkins pod(s) are themselves running in a container (docker or otherwise) inside the kubernetes cluster. It can be very tricky to run docker inside a container. There is a lot of help out there on how to do it - search for "docker in docker" or "dind", but there are a lot of reasons you do not want to do that. Security being a big issue here.

Instead, you may consider some other way to build your container images, without using a docker command. Search for "building containers without docker" or something similar. My favourite is to use [kaniko](https://github.com/GoogleContainerTools/kaniko). Kaniko avoids the issues of running docker inside a container, and is compatible with the same Dockerfile you already use.

There are other ways to do this as well. Searching will give some good results.

Comment: Hey @dlaidlaw,
Thanks for the clarification specially the point about this setup being a security concern. But what I'm confused about is that this setup used to work without DIND setup before (I followed the tutorial on this https://cloud.google.com/solutions/jenkins-on-kubernetes-engine-tutorial before they started using helm). Do you know if jenkins, docker or GKE stopped supporting a feature that made this not work. Or Am i missing something?

Comment: @devops_enthusiast No, I don't know of anything. But of course that is not an indication that something was not changed. I actually now use kaniko exclusively to build my images in my CI pipelines so I never run into this type of issue any more. However, you can check your setup - sometimes if you are using a latest tag somewhere you can pull in stuff that is broken. Even when using convenience tags, this can be a problem.